Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
I encountered this problem, whether in WSL_Ubuntu or on my Ubuntu server, the result is the same.
(base) wsl_ubuntu@DESKTOP-9F3TF7P:~$ sudo docker pull python:3.9-slim
[sudo] password for wsl_ubuntu:
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
(base) wsl_ubuntu@DESKTOP-9F3TF7P:~$

I have tried using a proxy server and adding some mirrors from my country in the daemon.json file, but none of them worked.
As a temporary solution, I am currently adopting this measure:  Here are the steps for directly transferring a Docker image:

Save Docker image as a tar file on Server A:
docker save myimage > myimage.tar


Transfer the tar file to Server B:
scp myimage.tar root@192.0.2.0:/home

Here, root@192.0.2.0 is the root user and IP address of Server B.

Load the tar file as a Docker image on Server B:
docker load < myimage.tar



But how should I effectively resolve this issue?
